# Highlight and make clickable nonregular area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a source code highlighter, and I'd like to highlight and make clickable a non-standard piece of code area.

For example, I'd like all the colored areas to be separately clickable.

[image]

As I understand it, implementing this with CSS is impossible. Though I can dynamically assign equal CSS classes to each span which belongs to same area (and modifying those via class selector). But then I have a problem, that each of those spans must be clickable. So I should also attach JS events to each span.

Overall this sounds like a zillion of spans with zillion of events, am I correct? Is there better solution?

Comment: the source code which I started with https://jsfiddle.net/xgtmoe8q/

Comment: JS events can be attached to the CSS classes directly.

Comment: @Sanxofon I'm not sure I understand. Is it possible to call JS from CSS? Or are you talking about :hover?